# CodeIgniter URL Changing

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing an application using CodeIgniter. In this case I would like to get URL like  `www.something.com/book/bookname` while I am clicking on an anchor tag of View.I would not like to get URL like `www.something.com/book/bookname/12`. On the other hand I have to pass book id from View to Controller.

Could anyone say how can I do that ??

Thanks

@Allendar

I failed to express.Sorry for that.Lets have a scenerio. I have a list of books in my `View`. Like below

Sl no      Name of book      Price

1. php book         $10
2. MySql book       $15
3. html book        $20
4. css book         $12

Now I would like to see details of a book. In this case I hiperlinked the book name, where the book id is inside a anchor tag. If I clicked on a book name  I'll get a URL like `www.something.com/book/get_book/12`. Where book is the name of `Controller`, get_book is a function inside the `Controller` and 12 is the book id. Then I can get details of a book  using the id 12 from database.This is the common secenerio in almost all applications.

But I need a special URL, that is `www.something.com/book/get_book/php book`. But I would like to get the id of the book in `Controller` to find out the book in database(`because id of the book is UNIQUE,but name of the book is not UNIQUE`).Even I would not like to get a URL like `www.something.com/book/get_book/php book/12`.

I think now it is clear to you.

Thanks

Comment: So you have a Book on a certain page, and then want to build an URL based on that Book's ID? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: In this case, you have to pass the book id as POST instead of GET. This way, it will not appear in the url.

Comment: You can pass book id through hidden value or query string.

Comment: @Allendar 

I have a Book on a certain page, and then want to build an URL based on that Book's NAME.In this way I can collect the book name from URL in Controller. But I would like to collect ID of the book in Controller.

Thanks

Comment: Oh so you want a pretty URL. You can do that, but that URL has to be generated when the Book is created in the database. Also you need to put an `UNIQUE` mark on that `slug`-field so it can never conflict.

Comment: @Allendar - 

Your reply is interesting. Could you please describe a little the database portion?? What is `slug` field ??


Thanks for your reply.

Comment: About slugs, read this page; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(web_publishing)#Slug

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pretty URL you can use slugs. A few simple steps would be, when creating a new Book in your database,

**1.) PHP (Generate Slugs for the new book)**

```
$book = new StdClass;
$book->name = $some_post_value['name'];
$book->slug = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '_', $book->name); // You should decide your own rules and check if there are no illegal URL-characters in your book-name
```

**2.) SQL (Check if the slug is already used)**

```
sprintf('SELECT * FROM books WHERE slug = "%s"', $book->slug);
```

If the result of the above query is ***1***, then it means the slug is already taken. You either need to add or change something in your slug and check with the same query again until the slug is absolutely unique.

When the slug is finally unique you can just insert the Book-data into your database and use your controller like so to eventually retrieve your Book by it's slug (name):

```
class Book extends FrontendController {

    public function bookname($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug) {
            // Assuming DataMapper here, for easy examples
            $book = new Book();
            $book->get_where(array('slug' => $slug));

            if ($book->exists()) {
                // Process and load your view with the Book-data
            }
            else{
                // Book not found by Slug
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Using `UNIQUE` on the `slug`-field in your database will spare you a lot of headaches in the future, as you might have conflicting slug-names in the table otherwise.

An URL would look like; `http://www.yourwebsite.com/book/bookname/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_Return_of_the_King`

Comment: You can use CI uri helper `url_title()` to convert title to slugs. [Read here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a "slug" column in your database table so you can match on that but also. But because it's not unique, you'll also need the ID (as you correctly pointed out).

so set the URL to:

```
book/get_book/php-book/12
```

and pass both arguments to the controller method

```
get_book($slug, $id)
```

Hope this helps!